# How do i append a user input into an array?

Tags: javascript

```
function test(){
    input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    array = [];
    result = array.push(input);
    console.log(typeof(result)) //returns number
}
```

So when i tries to add the user input into an array it keeps returning numbers, did i do something wrong?

Comment: please consider putting the full code. make it so that we can run it directly from your question and help you.

Answer (score 0):

You were using `typeof(result)` which returns the type of your variable `result`. The type is your case `number`.

To see what is inside of `result`, simle use `console.log(result);`.

[More about the typeof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Answer (score 0):

You’re doing it right; you’re just logging the wrong thing. Array.push mutates the array by adding an element to it and returns the length of the array, not the array itself. You can get rid of the `result` variable. After `array.push(input)`, `console.log(array)` should give you the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have done it the right way but you're not logging the right thing to the browser console. Try `console.log(result)` instead.
Maybe you can try doing it like this and see the behavior. Hope it helps!

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', add); 
function add() {
    const array = [];
    let val = document.getElementById('inp').value;
    array.push(val);
    console.log('The array is = ', array);
}
```

```html
 <div>
   <button id="btn">add</button>
   <input id="inp" type="text"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! it helps a lot (for a beginner)!

Comment: Glad it helped!